# Display users in room based on variable provided by Context API Socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io

I've created an online chat app using Socket.io. The users are allowed to input their own room in order to chat with others in that same room. I'd like to display a list of active users that are currently located within the room given by the context api. Here is my code:

```
const ChatMembers = ({ socket }) => {
const currentUser = useContext(AuthContext);
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const { room } = useContext(RoomContext);

useEffect(() => {
   socket.on("newUserResponse", (data) => setUsers(data));
}, [socket, users]);
<div>
{users.map((user) => (
              <p key={user.socketID}>{user.currentUser.displayName}</p>
            ))}
</div>
```

I was thinking of mapping over the users given to me by socket.io with a conditional. The problem is I'm not sure on how to put a conditional inside a map function. I wanted to compare the user's room value to the value of the room context. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating during mapping an array can be done as follows:

`{users.map(user => { if (user.somevalue === othervalue)  { your code} ))};`